# Visual Studio unable to connect to mac server

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

So I have a Xamarin project that I want to test on ios using a mac as a simulator.
everything is set up correctly(as far as I know).

but when I try to run it it says: "Unable to connect to Mac Server with Address='some address i don't wanna share' and User='user' The build can't continue without a connection XamerinAPP.iOS"

I went all over the internet but can't find a solution to my problem.
If you can help then that would be great.

If you need more information just ask.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tested ssh between your PC and Mac?  Are both machines using the same version of the tools?   Have you followed the troubleshooting guide?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/troubleshooting

Comment: First try to connect with both IP and Machine Name.  Sometimes one will work and other will not work.  To debug I would try to ping (try both IP and Machine name) to see if you have a route.  It is not clear if error is due to a connection failure or a credential failure.  I usually use Putty to connect before trying from code to make sure it is my code and not the connection.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

So for some reason when I tried to connect a few times using the IP it worked. I dont know what caused it to work but I am happy.

After that it said that I was missing an image in the 'xamarinapp.IOS', so after fixing that everything worked. I think personally that I entered the wrong IP adress when I wanted to connect.